# Rewriting expression (Properties of Exponents)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Hey so I have a question, I have to rewrite $$a^\frac{1}{2}(2a^{2}-4a^{-1})$$ which is:$$2a^\frac{5}{2} -4a^\frac{-1}{2}$$ I'm confused as to why this doesn't evaluate to $$-2a^{2}$$

Comment: Could explain why you think the answer can be $-2a^2$ in the question?

Comment: I actually thought you can $2a - 4a = -2a$ and then substract the $^-1/2$  for it to be $-2a^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$2a^{5/2}-4a^{-1/2}=2a^{5/2}-\frac{4}{a^{1/2}}=\frac{2a^3-4}{a^{1/2}}$$